# What arguments to use to switch from graphical design entry (HDL)?

Tags: fpga, hdl

I am an experienced FPGA designer with background in Information Technology and therefore used to GIT and Test Driven development for FPGA designs. Of course flow was automated by Make scripts, so using GUI was never necessary.
I have even used a bit of goodies that MyHDL offers (like testing directly from python using Numpy, using signal classes etc).

In my current job the section is using graphical design entry for HDL.

I had a presentation where I presented my concerns about this design approach. Of which is that binary files are hard to version, inefficiency of graphical entry and lack of automated tests.
The lack of scriptability of the tool (the resulting design must be generated using GUI...) which leads to inefficiency.

But the old electrical engineers seems to be reluctant to even consider using plain VHDL with scripted Flow not speaking about allowing me to use MyHDL on new projects.

My question is therefore for seasoned EEs how they were if ever persuaded to use plain-text entry? What kind of arguments should I use?
And for younger what arguments they used to get rid of the graphical HDL atrocity?

Comment: Are they really doing FPGA development without a testbench? Ouch. There are a few good Q&As on workplace.stackexchange on "how do I introduce working practice improvements when I'm the new guy" that may help.

Comment: Well, sort of. The tool allow you to create stimulus by drawing signal into thing that looks like waveform viewer and they stare at the waveform to see if the unit/design is working properly. No assertions, no automatic evaulation..

Comment: A good argument is "So long, I got a job at a place that isn't still using 1980's design methods."

Comment: Another strategy is to send the old-schoolers to modern training.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is therefore for seasoned EEs how they were if ever persuaded to use plain-text entry?

I'm not a seasoned EE, not by a long shot. But I do have VHDL experience and one of my jobs consisted of using a combination of VHDL and Python, much like you describe in your question. GUI-style development was simply not allowed. It took some time to get used to, but I never went back.

The testability of one's VHDL improves by so much when not using the GUI that I now consider working without the only 'proper' way of developing it.

Of-course, when going the text-only route, make sure you provide your developers with a text-editor they feel comfortable with. Notepad is too limited and advanced editors like Vi or Emacs can be considered a too big step if combined with dropping GUI-style development.

> What kind of arguments should I use?

That will mostly depend on the company culture. Focus on issues they're currently having which would be solved, mitigated or otherwise made less problematic when switching to text-only. Testability, maintainability and the ability for more flexibility during prototyping come to mind. Don't forget the extra advantages in version control either.

Keep in mind switching from one style to another company-wide is a big thing. It won't be easy and you'll need support of a lot of people to get it working. Otherwise it won't work as well as expected (people 'cheating' the system by doing it their way anyway) and it's one gigantic waste of time and effort.

Comment: Actually I have proposed using Sigasi (since we do actually have a license for that - other sections are using it) that also allows you to visualize text based design. Anyway thank you for the tips :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be a difficult argument to make when people like GUIs.

However, take a team using graphical entry, and then live through the horror of having to change tool, target, or even **tool version** that breaks the existing file format. In our case the tool vendor got bought up, and the next version was incompatible. Their 'auto-migrate' tool did exactly what you would expect, it automated all the easy bits, and obfuscated the difficult corner cases. Progress stopped for 6 months while we got back to where we were.

After that the argument makes itself, plain VHDL is the only sensible way to go, graphical is dropped like a hot brick. You control your text testbench, your versioning, everything.

I guess ask the team what they will do when (not if) the graphical tool file format changes.